# DOMDocument inside typescript file

Tags: html, typescript

I have a typescript file where I need to access to the DOM document, my problem is the `document.getElementByClassName('name')` is undefined. If I print will show on the console of course but that is because the console is reading the live document. And it seems to me that the typescript file aren't or take some time to do it.

I'm using vue3 with vite and typescript, but I think the use of vu3 or vite is not related to this problem.

The file structure is

- vue file
- Typescript file

Inside the vue file I call the `const API = new ClassName(sections, option)`. So far so good nothing to report here. But inside the typescript file I have a class that does some stuff with window and document from the HTML and some times work.

My typescript file looks like this

```js
export class ClassName {
    sections: number[]
    options: OptionsInterface
    current: number
    
    constructor(sections: number[], options: OptionsInterface){
      this.sections = sections
      this.options = options
      this.current = 0
      this.init()
    }

    init():void {
      this.setEvents()
    }

    setEvents(): void {
       document.addEventListener("wheel", (e) => this.handleWheel(e), false) // this works fine
    }

    handleWheel(e): void {
         //here find if is moving up or down nothing to report
     if (delta < 0) this.move('up')
     else this.move('down')
    }

    move(type: string): void {
      if (type === 'down') this.moveDown()
      else this.moveUp()
    }
    
    // the move up and move down do the same in different directions
    moveUp(): void {
      this.current ++;
      let next = this.current
      if (next > this.sections.length - 1) {
         next = this.sections.length - 1
         this.current = next;
      }
      if (next < this.sections.length) {
        this.moveTo(next, null, false)
      }
    }
 
    moveTo(element: number, callback, isMovementUp: boolean): void {
      if(element === null) return;
      if(element === 0) window.scrollTo({top: 0, behavior: 'smooth'})
      else document.getElementsByClassName('section')[element].scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'}) // this one is not working
    }
   
}
```

The up code is an example since I can not share all the code with you. If I add a breakpoint in the browser this not working step starts working. If I input this code inside the vue file everything works.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This probably has to do with the fact that you should not manipulate the DOM directly from within a Vue application, using code such as `document.getElementsByClassName`. Instead you should ask the Vue app for a reference to the element.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I test it with the ref and the issue persists, but I found what is causing the issue and I fix I will test it again the close in the typecript file and update the question. Thank you for the help